# Error in creating Reference variable for Realtime firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from database.. very basic reading process ..

The variable reference and getInstance() shown in red and many other methods and variables in the new class called ModelPrediction..

The firebase is connected and everything for me is correct but I don't know what is the problem, please help ..

```
package com.example.iwork;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ModelPrediction {
   //Writ This is in the top
    DatabaseReference reference;

//For connecting realtime with Android
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Here make sure the child name is same as FB (capital or not)
         reference.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //To recive and display the data you need to have a class in andrid studio with String variables
            User userType = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            String UserType = userType.role;


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                
            }
        });
}
```

Edit :

For more clarification, the error in the reference object is `create type parameter 'reference'` and Unknown class: 'reference'..

and the error for getInstance() method `can't resolve symbol 'getInstance'`
and all the things below and related to these two errors are also error..

Comment: Hey, can you please clarify the error by logs or better explanation?

Comment: @ValiSpaceProgramming thanks for replying, Edited I hope now it's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, wait! The answer is simple.
Your code is not right, because you are executing code not in a method but in a raw class. You should always try to put your code into a method, here is an example:

```
public class Hello {
   public void foo(){
      System.out.println("foo");
   }
}
```

Your code looks like this:

```
public class Hello {
   System.out.println("foo");
}
```

I hope i could help you. Your code should be reformatted into this:

```
package com.example.iwork;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ModelPrediction {
    
    DatabaseReference reference;

    public void doSomething() {

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        reference.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
          ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               
                User userType = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                String UserType = userType.role;
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```